# AWS S3 static site only for a group of people

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

There is a static website on AWS S3 bucket.
This site has to be available only for one team. It could be authentication system, or access via AWS Client VPN Endpoint (only this team uses AWS VPN).

I have read about S3 Access Points, VPC Endpoints, Bucket Policy with VPC and IP-restriction, made some experiments. There was an idea to restrict access only for VPC with VPN. But I can not forward bucket traffic to VPN tunnel, because my bucket IP address changes all the time.

And this way doesn't look straight.

What service or service combination can I use to implement restriction with minimum efforts?

Comment: Please read this article: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/ It has a section on "Securing your content"

Answer (score 0):

One approach I have done in the past is using an API Gateway as a proxy to static UI content hosted in a private S3 bucket.  You can either use a public or private APIGW. With public you will need an [APIGW resource policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-examples.html#apigateway-resource-policies-source-vpc-example) to restrict access to the VPC-endpoint. You can also use a private APIGW-- the only downside is AWS doesn't support custom DNS for private api gateways (you will be accessing your site using a url similar to `https://{rest-api-id}-{vpce-id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/{stage}`-- [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-api-test-invoke-url.html)).  AWS also offers good [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-s3.html) on creating an apigw as an s3 proxy.

In this example the flow of traffic would go: client-> vpn -> vpc endpoint -> apigw -> s3

Hopefully this helps!